# Display search results from both local DB and remote service

Tags: android, json, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I have an app that stores items in a local database, displayed to the user using a `ListView`, also in the layout is an `EditText` that can be used to filter the list.  All of this works fine, my issue is I would also like to include items returned by a web service (JSON) in this list also.  I'm not having an issue parsing the JSON, my issue is simply how do I insert/add the results from the web service to the ListView?

The data for the ListView comes from a cursor handled by a SimpleCursorAdapter, I just can not figure out how to add the items from the JSON results to the Cursor (I don't actually think you can write to a Cursor outside of performing a Query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to insert the JSON results into the local DB, then one approach would be to use an ArrayAdapter to back the ListView. You can then populate the array by inserting results from the cursor and the JSON query.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: That was one approach I was trying to avoid, all the other db functions return cursors, but I guess I could write a "converter" and pass all the functions through it so I don't have to re-write them all.

Comment: After giving it some thought I think it would be simpler/cleaner to modify the table structure by adding a source field (user or service), inserting the JSON results, then running the query.  Thanks for your help.